# Handling development time web.config conflicts

Tags: asp.net, git, visual-studio-2017, web-config

I am looking for a way to handle this challenge: we are a geographically dispersed dev team using ASP.NET Web API and Angular to build a web app.

The thing that causes the grief is the fact that not all team members use the same database setup for their dev work. Yes, I know - I can use `web.config` transforms to set the proper connection strings for test, staging and production (and I'm already doing this) - but this is not what I'm talking about.

Due to reasons beyond our control at this time, we have

- some developers working on a local SQL Server instance using `server=(local);database=OurDB` as their connection string
- other developers using a central developer SQL Server in their location, using something like `server=someserver.mycorp.com;database=OurDB`
- and a few exotic cases with yet other settings

Now every time someone commits a change to the Git repo, and happens to also change something in the web.config, his connection string is committed to the repo. So when I then go pull that latest commit, my settings to my local DB server are overwritten by this other guy's settings.

I am looking for a way to handle this - I was hoping I might be able to

- hook into the Git pull process and automagically update the `web.config` connection string to my local needs whenever I pull something
- somehow reference a connection string (or external config file) based on e.g. my currently logged in user's name or something like that

But I can't seem to find any way of doing this. I was wondering if I need to build a VS extension to handle this - any starters for that? Has anyone done something like this before and could share his code? (or has it up on Github)

Comment: I too have this issue. By default our web.config points to our `Dev 1` environment, but we have a PowerShell script to change the config to be suitable for that particular dev's local machine environment. And if the developer isn't careful, those settings can get committed. We have a small team, so mostly we handle that via manual enforcement on Pull Requests. I think the best way around this is to read the settings from either an external (or Git ignored) file, or a settings database, or environment variables. Similar to the way ASP.NET Core can handle it.

Comment: Have you already considered asking git to disregard changes to this file with `git update-index --assume-unchanged`? That way developers can go crazy with a file and not mess up their revisions.

Comment: @eftshift0 But what if a developer does need to change the web.config file (for example, adding a new setting)? So you want the new setting to be committed, but not the change to the dev's  local connection string.

Comment: @mason: yes, I was wondering if I could use something like environment variables or similar - but since I'm **not** on .NET Core (yet), this doesn't seem to be a viable option, really ....

Comment: This kind of stuff I take care by keeping a sample file that I actually keep track of and a real ignored file that is created from the sample file.

Comment: I think environment variables are still an option. It just might be a pain to switch to, depending on how scattered your references to your config file are. For example if you're only referencing `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString` in one place, you could easily change that to `isLocalDevelopment ? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyDB") : ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString;`

Comment: I think it really comes down to structuring your app so that there's a single place to get particular configuration. If you've been diligent about that, using environment variables or other sources besides web.config should be fairly trivial. In my particular case, I've inherited a giant Web Forms app that has many reference to the web.config, including custom configuration sections, WCF bindings etc.

Comment: I haven't tried this...but the [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.1) namespace is all in [.NET Standard 2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/2.2.0-preview3-35497). Perhaps you could leverage that, even in .NET Framework and non-Core ASP.NET? I bet someone has built an extension for web.config to plug into that.

Comment: @mason: thanks - if you package up all your comments into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web.config configuration system used in ASP.NET is not flexible enough to support the more advanced scenario you have described. So, why use it? You could store the configuration in files within the repository, one per developer. Or they could be stored outside the repository or otherwise ignored.

The real trick is that most older applications don't have a single root that retrieve the configuration, so you have to refactor your application to utilize a flexible configuration system. For your staging/production environments you probably still want to use the config in web.config. The following code can give you a basic idea of one way to structure it:

```
public class MyApplicationConfiguration
{
    public string MainConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigurationRetriever
{
    public MyApplicationConfiguration GetConfiguration()
    {
        // You might look for the absence or presence of an environment variable to determine this
        bool isLocalDevelopment = IsApplicationLocalDevelopment();

        var config = new MyApplicationConfiguration();

        if(isLocalDevelopment)
        {
            config.MainConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyApplication_MainConnectionString");

            //or get it from a JSON file or XML file or config database
        }
        else
        {
            config.MainConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

Rather than rolling your own config building logic, you might refactor your application to leverage [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.1). It's not just for .NET Core. It's for .NET Standard. So you can use it even in your legacy ASP.NET applications. For reading the web.config, you could probably use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml. Or you can write your own adapter that pulls values out of ConfigurationManager. I did a basic test, and this worked as expected.

Comment: What's that `IsApplicationLocalDevelopment` method call? Is that your own "homegrown" thing, or is that something I can check in a legacy ASP.NET app?

Comment: @marc_s it’s just a place holder I had for detecting which set of configs to use. You could assume local unless a certain app setting is present (your release process would add that for production release). Or do it based on machine name, or based on the presence of an environment variable etc.